# Prove that if $s_n → +∞$ as $n → ∞$ then the sequence $\sqrt{|s_n|}$ is not bounded

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, analysis

> State the definition of boundedness of a sequence. Prove that if $s_n
>  \to +\infty$ as $n \to \infty$ then the sequence $\sqrt{|s_n|}$ is not bounded. Argue
>   directly from the definition of boundedness and the definition of
>   divergence to $+\infty$.

A sequence is $a_n$ is bounded if $\exists M \in \mathbb{R}$ such that $|a_n| \lt M$ for every natural number $n$.

$S_n \to +\infty$ as $n \to \infty$ means for any $M\gt0$ there exists $N \in \mathbb{R}$ such that if $n\gt N$ then $S_n \gt M$, meaning $S_n$ is unbounded above.

I thought of saying $S_n \gt M \implies |S_n| \gt |M| \implies \sqrt{|S_n|}\gt\sqrt{|M|}.$

But I'm not too sure if it would be legal to operate on the absolute value like that. What should I do?

Comment: Of course it is legal since with absolute value everything becomes non-negative.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take *any* $\;M\in\Bbb R_+\;$ , so there exists $\;N\in\Bbb N\;$ such that $\;n>N\implies s_n>M^2\;$ ( and observe that we can safely asume already that $\;s_n>0\;$ for $\;n>N\;$) , and thus for this same $\;n>N\;$ we get $\;\sqrt{s_n}>\sqrt{M^2}=M\;$